Why using CAS operation when a segment is empty in Java ConcurrentHashMap
As we all know, when adding an element, ConcurrentHashMap will use CAS operation to add a new node if a segment is empty; if the segment is not empty, it will use Synchronized to lock the current segment and try to put again. This can avoid the lock granularity under the segment lock mechanism being too large, and the lock competition problem caused by too many threads in high concurrency scenarios, and improve concurrency performance.
But the question is why we should use CAS operation instead of Synchronized or others when a segment is empty. What are the advantages compared to that?
I can't find any analysis on this problem. Although I have my own thoughts, I prefer to see other ideas.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
